# Is there a Nuget package to create Azure Function Apps?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, nuget-package, azure-functions, azure-management-api

I need to create multiple Azure Function apps in different geographic locations over and over, so I need to automate this. Doing this in the Portal isn't going to scale. I thought there would be a Nuget package for doing this, but I haven't found it yet. Any ideas on how to automate the creation of Azure Function Apps?

Comment: Update, I found this link helpful to get started using Azure Resource Manager to deploy templates with .Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/virtual-machines-windows-csharp-template?toc=%2fazure%2fvirtual-machines%2fwindows%2ftoc.json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an Azure Functions specific NuGet package or API. Functions works with the standard [Azure Resource Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview) APIs (consistent with the way you manage other Azure services) and new Function Apps can be provisioned using PowerShell, the Azure CLI, the ARM API or directly through the portal.

Under the "Get Started" section of the documentation I've linked to, you can find more information on how to create and manage templates.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Ok so it looks like Resource Manager APIs are the new way to go. Thanks Fabio!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no Nuget Package for you to do this. Per my understanding, you could leverage ARM template to create your Azure Function App. 
You could try to follow the [issue](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/8) & [code sample](https://github.com/SyntaxC4-MSFT/CoderCards) on GitHub about deploying Azure Function Apps with ARM to create the Azure Function App in multiple geographic locations as expected.

Also, you could follow this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy) about deploying your resources to Azure with Resource Manager templates via Azure Power Shell.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, I love the "Deploy to Azure" single click button from the GitHub example you linked to.